# Replicating jQuery's $('body').outerHeight(true) without jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some pages which load into an iframe in a parent page and I am using postMessage to send the height of the child page to the parent so it can resize the iframe. The child pages are very simple and it seems a shame to have the extra size of jQuery just to find the height of the body. However I haven't so far been able to replicate the effect of the above call in straight JavaScript.

I've tried differing combinations of scrollHeight, offsetHeight and clientHeight applied to the body and to body.documentElement but none match. And they are very different in different browsers, especially if you switch between child documents of widely differing sizes. Here is the actual code of the onload event handler for all the child pages:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("height(1) = " + document.body.scrollHeight + "\n" +
        "height(2) = " + document.documentElement.scrollHeight + "\n" +
        "height(3) = " + document.body.offsetHeight + "\n" +
        "height(4) = " + document.documentElement.offsetHeight + "\n" +
        "height(5) = " + document.body.clientHeight + "\n" +
        "height(6) = " + document.documentElement.clientHeight + "\n" +
        "height(7) = " + $('body').outerHeight(true)
    );
    parent.postMessage($('body').outerHeight(true) + "px", "*");
}
```

None of the first six values matches the seventh in each browser (IE8/FF/Chrome) in each circumstance. The second one is nearest but it fails in Chrome when switching from a large child page to a smaller one - it still gives the size of the previous page.

I did read the source of jQuery but my JavaScript isn't good enough to work out what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look through the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js).

```
// outerHeight and outerWidth
jQuery.fn[ "outer" + name ] = function( margin ) {
    var elem = this[0];
    return elem ?
        elem.style ?
        parseFloat( jQuery.css( elem, type, margin ? "margin" : "border" ) ) :
        this[ type ]() :
        null;
};
```

Comment: I did read the code but I didn't understand it.

Debugging jQuery.fn.outerHeight with FireBug reveals that it is using jQuery.css to get the result. But single-stepping through that just gets me lost in a nest of recursive calls and renamed functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').outerHeight(true) = document.body.height + document.body.marginTop + document.body.marginBottom + document.body.bordorTop + document.body.borderBottom
```

Comment: Hmm - document.body.height etc don't seem to exist. document.body.style.height etc do exist but are blank.

Comment: el.style.height only returns the value of the currently applied style from CSS, which may be empty, "auto", etc. What you want is the actual numeric pixel value, which is what [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) gets you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery then goes into the cssHooks function and it all starts to get hairy. On reflection it seems pointless spending time trying to work out what it's doing; I should just use it. I use it in the parent page so all the browsers will have cached it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Masonry have a function - getWH() - refactored from Jquery which should do what you need:
https://github.com/desandro/vanilla-masonry

```
// returns width/height of element, refactored getWH from jQuery
function getWH( elem, measure, isOuter ) {
    // Start with offset property
    var isWidth = measure !== 'height',
        val = isWidth ? elem.offsetWidth : elem.offsetHeight,
        dirA = isWidth ? 'Left' : 'Top',
        dirB = isWidth ? 'Right' : 'Bottom',
        computedStyle = getStyle( elem ),
        paddingA = parseFloat( computedStyle[ 'padding' + dirA ] ) || 0,
        paddingB = parseFloat( computedStyle[ 'padding' + dirB ] ) || 0,
        borderA = parseFloat( computedStyle[ 'border' + dirA + 'Width' ] ) || 0,
        borderB = parseFloat( computedStyle[ 'border' + dirB + 'Width' ] ) || 0,
        computedMarginA = computedStyle[ 'margin' + dirA ],
        computedMarginB = computedStyle[ 'margin' + dirB ],
        marginA, marginB;

    if ( !supportsPercentMargin ) {
        computedMarginA = hackPercentMargin( elem, computedStyle, computedMarginA );
        computedMarginB = hackPercentMargin( elem, computedStyle, computedMarginB );
    }

    marginA = parseFloat( computedMarginA ) || 0;
    marginB = parseFloat( computedMarginB ) || 0;

    if ( val > 0 ) {

        if ( isOuter ) {
            // outerWidth, outerHeight, add margin
            val += marginA + marginB;
        } else {
            // like getting width() or height(), no padding or border
            val -= paddingA + paddingB + borderA + borderB;
        }

    } else {

        // Fall back to computed then uncomputed css if necessary
        val = computedStyle[ measure ];
        if ( val < 0 || val === null ) {
            val = elem.style[ measure ] || 0;
        }
        // Normalize "", auto, and prepare for extra
        val = parseFloat( val ) || 0;

        if ( isOuter ) {
            // Add padding, border, margin
            val += paddingA + paddingB + marginA + marginB + borderA + borderB;
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

[edit] you will also need to grab hackPercentMargin and getStyle from vanilla-masonry.js